# AngularJS route

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes

Estou com uma aplicação web em spring boot e uso Angular na parte das rotas. Está tudo funcionando, mas quando atualizo a página, se não estiver na `home`, apresenta um erro e, quando altero algo em algum arquivo HTML, ele não aparece.

Rotas

```
var app = angular.module('appRadio',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // remove o # da url
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider

    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "app/views/home.html",
        controller  :"HomeCtrl",
    })
    .when("/enviarMusicas", {
        templateUrl : "app/views/enviarMusicas.html",
        controller  : "enviarMusicaCtrl"
    })
    .when("/contato", {
        templateUrl : "app/views/contato.html",
        controller  : "ContatoCtrl"
    })
    .when("/musicas", {
        templateUrl : "app/views/musica.html",
        controller  : "MusicaCtrl"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });
});
```

Controllers

```
app.controller('MusicaCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope, $location,$http) {
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabela').DataTable( {
            "scrollY":        "300px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging":         false
        });
    });

    $http.get("/musica/buscarTodas").then(function(response) {
        $scope.musicas = response.data;
        console.log($scope.musicas);
    },function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.path = $location.path();
});

app.controller('enviarMusicaCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();

    $scope.tipos = [
        {valor:"Mp4"},
        {valor:"Mp3"},
        {valor:"CD"},
        {valor:"DVD"},
        {valor:"JPG"},
        {valor:"PNG"}
    ];

    $scope.musica;
});

app.controller('ContatoCtrl', function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
});
```

Comment: não entendi ,eu sou novato com angular .rsrs

Comment: Basicamente é isso: Se você usar `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` para remover o marcador '#' você precisa definir, na página inicial, um elemento `base`, além de outras possíveis configurações do lado do servidor.

Comment: no index ta assim <base href="/" />